# Find the value $\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \,\mathrm dx$ without words

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ such that: $$f(0)=1,\quad f(0.5)=5, \quad f(1)=15$$
>
> Find: $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \,\mathrm dx$$

It is said that it can be solved without words.

Comment: $Kavi No,It is right

Comment: That depends what is your definition of a 'word'.

Comment: The answers that had a chance to make it show that a good hint would have been much better than playing the MSEthical correctness card.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 f(x) \ dx = \dfrac{1-0}{6}\left(f(0)+4f(0.5)+f(1)\right)=6$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio [Simpson’s rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) error is in $f^{(4)}(\xi)$. Therefore exact for a degree $3$ polynomial.

Comment: You are right, my bad. All the cubic polynomials fulfilling $f(0)=A, f(1/2)=B, f(1)=C$ have the same integral over $(0,1)$ since they differ by a multiple of $x(x-1/2)(x-1)$ which has integral zero.

Comment: Nice! But since the solution is not complete without your explanatory comment, and that comment contained words, I don't think this counts as a solution “without words” (whatever *that* was supposed to mean to begin with).

Comment: @HansLundmark A solution without word can be a big debate. If you know Simpson’s rule, you don’t need words. Just like you don’t need words to explain why multiplication of reals is commutative. All depends on what you accept as given backgrounds....

Comment: Yes, I agree. My comment was more of a criticism towards the question than towards your answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: your explanation for polynomials is simpler to understand than error analysis of Simpson's rule. +1 for your comment. +1 for the current answer also.

Answer (score 8):

$f(0) = 1\implies d = 1, f(0.5) = 5 \implies \dfrac{a}{8} +\dfrac{b}{4} + \dfrac{c}{2} = 4, f(1) = 15 \implies 2a+2b+2c = 28\implies \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \dfrac{a}{4}+\dfrac{b}{3}+\dfrac{c}{2}+d= \dfrac{3a+4b+6c}{12}+1=\dfrac{32+28}{12}+1 = 6$

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x) = s + t(x-.5)^2 + u(x-.5) + v(x-.5)^3. \tag{1} $$
$$ f(.5) = 5 \implies s=5. \tag{2} $$
$$ 16 = 1 + 15 = f(0) + f(1) = 2\cdot 5 + t/2 + 0 + 0 \implies \, t = 12. \tag{3} $$
$$ \int f(x) \,dx = 5x + 4(x-.5)^3 + u (x-.5)^2/2 + v(x-.5)^4/4. \tag{4} $$
$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx = 5 + 4(1/8+1/8) + u\,0 + v\,0 = 6. \tag{5} $$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a definite real number.

To see that, you have to solve the system of equations which you are given and express all parameters in terms of $a$ (say). Then you can evaluate the integral and the $a$'s will cancel out.

I'm going to leave the work to you.